difference in nuance and frequency of usage between "Who'd have known?" and "Who knew?"
I think the title of the following post is grammatically incorrect but am not sure what it was meant to be. I guess it should be "Who'd have known?" or "Who knew?"

I wonder

if "Who'd have known?" and "Who knew?" convey the same nuance.

if so, which is more commonly used.



who'd knew=not grammatical in English.

"Who knew?" is a "set phrase" - sometimes expressing genuine surprise, but usually an ironic response to some banal observation (similar to "No shit, Sherlock!").
"Who'd have known?" isn't a particularly common rhetorical question - we usually say "Who'd have thought?"


OP's cited text "Who'd knew?" is syntactically invalid, and would never be produced by a native Anglophone. It's just evidence of the fact that "Who knew?" has become something of a "global meme generator" for quirky / banal clickbait posts.

Thank you very much.

People of my generation (although not me) sometimes say 'Who'da thunk it?' with the same ironic intent. My father, born 1920, used to say 'Who would Christmas Eve it?'.

To clarify @MichaelHarvey' s comment - thunk is a humorous version of thought and  Christmas Eve is here a rhyming slang for believe.

I'm "more or less" Cockney, and my housemate is definitely Cockney. And "Would you Adam 'n' Eve it? Neither of us have ever encountered Christmas Eve in rhyming slang".

@FumbleFingers - https://www.englishtrackers.com/english-blog/seasonal-slang-things-christmas/

@MichaelHarvey: Your link is obviously willing to bend the truth a bit to suit their xmas theme. I didn't look, but I suppose they'll have mince pies. Whatever - Google Books returns at least 200 hits for "would you adam and eve it", but I see just 5 different matches for "would you christmas eve it".
